# Mat Paginator is not working properly when used inside a Modal pop up

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator, angular-material-paginator

I'm loading my datasource dynamically from API response inside a modal popup but it seems like Paginator is always undefined as my viewChild MatPaginator is on a modal pop up that open upon a button click.

tried this solution ([this link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205)) but no luck

can somebody help me with this. below is screenshot of my code

initialization

[image]

setting datasource from api response

[image]

final console result where i'm unable to get the pagination reference

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue with :

```
setTimeout(() => this.previewResultValues.paginator = this.paginator);
```

I hope this can help someone one day.

Comment: strange but it works, thank bro

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Directive,OnInit,Optional,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPaginator]',
  exportAs: '[appPaginator]'
})
export class PaginatorDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() paginatorLoaded:EventEmitter <MatPaginator> = new EventEmitter<MatPaginator>()
  ngOnInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (this.table && this.sort)
        (this.table.dataSource as any).sort=this.sort
      if (this.paginator)
        this.paginatorLoaded.emit(this.paginator)
    })
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private sort:MatSort,@Optional() private table:MatTable<any>,@Optional() private paginator:MatPaginator){}
}
```

```html
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="DataSource" appPaginator #Sort="matSort" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="SrNo">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="commonHeaderCSS"> SrNo
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;">
            {{ i+1 }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
         <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsForApiFilterCount"></tr>
        <tr mat-row class="example-element-row"
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsForApiFilterCount; let i = index;"></tr>
      </table>
      
       <mat-paginator appPaginator (paginatorLoaded)="DataSource.paginator=$event" class="mt-3" [pageSize]="10"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[15,30,50,100]">
    </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).